# What is the currently supported VNC Server for Ubuntu desktop 22.10?

Tags: vnc

The threads about this topic all seem to be quite old. I need to access a computer running Ubuntu desktop 22.10 from a Windows computer using VNC Viewer. What is the currently supported VNC Server?

I'm looking for open-source, not licensed.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I would have tagged this as vnc-server, but that tag doesn't exist and this is my first post.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly with what you have tried and the results obtained. If VNC is available in the repos you can be reasonably assured it is the latest supported version.